# Group users by created_at and insert into hash for MorrisJs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I want to use MorrisJs-Rails to build up a graphical statistic of user registered within the last 4 weeks.

For that I iterate through each day of the last month and check for users registered at this specific date. Here's the problem though.

**admin_helper.rb**:

```
def users_chart_date
  (4.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      {
        created_at: date,
        count: User.where("created_at = ? ", date).count
      }
  end
end
```

Both dates are stored like so:

```
puts User.first.created_at # => Tue, 10 Mar 2015 20:08:18 UTC +00:00
puts date # => Thu, 23 Jul 2015
```

You can see there's quite the difference between those two stored dates thus I can not possibly get an actual count of users registered per day.

Is there a way to "cast" my SQL query somehow? I feel the solution to my problem is easy peasy, but I can't seem to get it.

Thanks for your help,
let me know if you need something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, the `created_at` timestamp is of type `DateTime` (or `Time`), so you're correct in that its not directly comparable with a `Date` type. You could compare it with a range of times for each day:

```
(4.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
  {
    created_at: date,
    count: User.where(created_at: date.to_time.all_day).count
  }
end
```

(Note that this will use the times for your computer's timezone.)

However, this method can become very slow especially if the time range becomes longer (e.g., over the entire life of your app), in which case a SQL `GROUP BY` statement work much faster. Again, you need to deal with a comparison by dates on a time data field, which is database-dependent. With MySQL or PostgreSQL you can:

```
User.group("DATE(created_at)").count
```

If you want to restrict the time periods you get data for:

```
User.where("created_at >= ?", 4.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day).group("DATE(created_at)").count
```

These queries will return a hash of `Date` objects to the count of users with `created_at` times on that day.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use the first approach, although slower it fits my needs for the moment (I am the only one able to access these data ;p).